# pandas - check for non unique values in dataframe groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have this simple dataframe `df`:

```
a,b
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,2
2,1
2,2
2,3
2,5
2,5
```

I would like to check whether there are duplicates in `b` with respect to each group in `a`. So far I did the following:

```
g = df.groupby('a')['b'].unique()
```

which returns:

```
a
1       [2, 3, 4]
2    [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

But what I would like to have is a list, for each group in `a`, with multiple occurrences in `b`. The expected output in this case would be:

```
a
1    [2]
2    [5]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
g=df.groupby('a')['b'].value_counts()
g.where(g>1).dropna()
```

Comment: The second line can be replaced with `g[g>1]`

Answer (score 9):

We can use `duplicated`

```
print(df[df.duplicated()].drop_duplicates())
```

Comment: I don't think drop duplicates is needed. Doesn't `df1[df1.duplicated()]` subset correctly?